# extrapolate boundary data of a 2d function

Tags: approximation, matlab, extrapolation

I have a function defined over a 2d domain.
I want to keep all the internal data, but the information near the boundaries are less accurate and I want to extrapolate them from the inner points.
Is there an easy way to do that using MATLAB?

Comment: A quick googling gave a lot of results, for examples [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit).

Comment: @DanielR thanks, but I'd rather avoiding extra functions. Is it possible to do something easily by myself?

Comment: @DanielR moreover that function does not work as I want..

Comment: I think I found a solution http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant-class.html perhaps I still need to code a little bit more, but then I'll post the solution here